# Why am I getting an error unwrapping these optionals?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The calculationField is a UITextField.

I have shown the optionals and removed the rest of the code. I am not used to debugging in xCode, so if you can provide some links to learning how to use xCode's debugging area, that would be great!

```
@IBAction func oneButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if isTyped == false {
    calculationField.text! = ""
    calculationField.text! += "1"
    isTyped = true
    } else {
        calculationField.text! += "1"
    } }
```

[error message shown on xCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k2GR.jpg)

Comment: Most likely, you haven't connected the text field in your storyboard to the outlet in your code.

Comment: It is connected.

Comment: Then how are you creating the view controller instance?  Is it coming from the storyboard?  Follow the debugging steps listed in the duplicate

Comment: I used the view controller they provided in the one view app with the main storyboard. I have changed my code up a bit, but still having problems.

Comment: Avoid `!`; set a breakpoint; examine your variables; see what is `nil`.  You can even use `print` statements if you don't want  to use the debugger.

Comment: Alright I'll check that